# Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5

Tags: angularjs

I have some problem with my AngularJS-app. I have tried to find some solutions on stackoverflow and so on. But i cant get rid off the problem at all. The error message it self, I understand, but i cant find the problem in my own code.

I have four different controllers in my project, two of them runs like i want - two of them doesnt. I pasted the code which works just fine (githubController), but krisController and eniroController doesnt work at all...

Please help

Thanks in advance

**app.js**

```
   (function(){
    var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/index.html", {
            templateUrl: "index.html",
            controller: "searchForData"
        })
            .when("/github/:username", {
            templateUrl: "templates/github.html",
            controller: "githubController"
        })
            .when("/tv/:channel", {
            templateUrl: "templates/tv.html",
            controller: "tvController"
        })
            .when("/eniroSearch/:searchword", {
            templateUrl: "templates/eniro.html",
            controller: "eniroController"
        })
            .when("/krisinfo", {
            templateUrl: "templates/krisInfo.html",
            controller: "krisController"
        })
            .otherwise({redirectTo:"/index"});
    });
}());
```

**eniroController.js**

```
(function() {
    var module = angular.module("app");    //Referens till modul

    var eniroController = function($scope, eniro, $routeParams){

        var onEniroComplete = function(data){
            $scope.eniro = data;
            $scope.eniroArray = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.eniro.adverts.length; i++){
                $scope.eniroArray[i] = $scope.eniro.adverts[i];
            }
        };

        var onError = function(reason) {
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
        };

        var eniroSearch = function(data){
            eniro.eniroSearch($scope.searchWord).then(onEniroComplete,onError);
        };   

        $scope.searchWord = $routeParams.searchword;
        eniro.eniroSearch($scope.searchWord).then(onEniroComplete, onError);
    };
    module.controller("eniroController", eniroController);
}());
```

**githubController**

```
    (function() {
    var app = angular.module("app");    //Referens till modul

    var githubController = function($scope, github, $routeParams){

        var onGithubComplete = function(data){
            $scope.user = data;
            github.getRepos($scope.user).then(onGitHubRepos, onError);
        };

        var onGitHubRepos = function(data){
            $scope.repos = data;
        };

        var onError = function(reason) {
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
        };

        $scope.username = $routeParams.username;
        github.getUser($scope.username).then(onGithubComplete, onError);
    };
    app.controller("githubController", githubController);
}());
```

**krisController**

```
(function(){
    var module = angular.module("app");

    var krisController = function($scope, kris, $routeParams) {

        var onFeedComplete = function(data){
            $scope.kris = data;
            $scope.krisArray = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.kris.Entries.length; i++){
                $scope.krisArray[i] = $scope.kris.Entries[i];
            }
        };

        var onError = function(reason) {
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
        };

        var getFeed = function(data){
            kris.getFeed.then(onFeedComplete, onError);
        };   
        kris.getFeed.then(onFeedComplete, onError);
    };

    module.controller("krisController", krisController);
}());
```

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/ng/areq?p0=krisController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at Error (native)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:6:449
>       at tb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:18:250)
>       at Qa (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:18:337)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:61:212
>       at link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js:7:180)
>       at K (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:49:142)
>       at f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:42:172)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:41:337
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:43:54

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>LXSU Angular-Project</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/eniroService.js"></script>
    <script src="js/eniroController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/githubService.js"></script>
    <script src="js/githubController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tvController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tvService.js"></script>
    <script src="js/search.js"></script>


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

  <body ng-controller="searchForData">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LXSU Angular-Project</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#"># <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="">#</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Search</h1>


          <div class="input-group">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(searchWord)">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." ng-model="searchWord">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>
                </form>
              </span>
          </div><!-- /input-group -->


          <h2 class="sub-header">{{ error }}</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive" >  
            <table class="table table-striped" ng-view>

            </table>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide your *"index.html"* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML page has scripts for some controllers, but not for all. They're thus not available to angular.

Missing (at least):

```
<script src="js/krisController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet... A typical beginner mistakes. Sorry for that, and thank you again. Now i have som other problems to solve ;)

Comment: You probably would have less problems to solve if you used the latest version of angular rather than a version that is almost 2 years old, and is thus full of bugs that have been fixed since.